# Adafruit Datalogger and Bluefruit LE issues

Tags: bluetooth, adafruit, datalogging

I'm having issues using the Adafruit Bluefruit LE shield at the same time as the Adafruit Datalogger shield. I can use either shield independently without issue. When I stack the two, I can talk with the SD card and the RTC on the datalogger, however, the Bluefruit fails all communication.

The Bluefruit is powered and I can connect to it via Bluetooth, however, it does not communicate with the Arduino at all.

I'm assuming there is a conflict over SPI, but I can't figure out the root cause. The SD chip select is 10. The Bluefruit chip select is 8. I have put 100 kΩ pullup resistors on both chip select pins, but that did not resolve the issue.

I've tried shield specific example sketches to remove coding / memory issues as a cause. These sketches work great until the shields are stacked. Once stacked, the Bluefruit loses all communication with the Arduino.